# Android error with R file - not fixed by cleaning/building in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging

I've spent the past two hours trying to figure this out -

I'm using Eclipse to try to learn Android development, and like hundreds of others, I'm having a problem with the R.layout.main file, and the same problem in any other activities. I've tried restarting (program and computer), refreshing, cleaning and building, but the R.java file doesn't only not get "fixed", but it doesn't get generated at all. I've also tried remaking the project from scratch, and it did the same thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you import `android.R`? That will cause big problems.

Comment: is gen/ folder in the build path ?

Comment: Try run the lint tool to see if you have any syntax errors in your xml files : http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

Comment: check your imports , see if something like Android.R. something etc is being imported and remove it.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried removing android.R, android.R.layout. I get an error when I try to import todo.whatever, as well as com.me.package.*; How can I add the gen/ folder to the build path? EDIT: both the src and gen folders are in the build path

Comment: Right button over gen/ -> Build Path -> add to Build Path

Comment: Also, the android.R file seems to be necessary even when I remove it, as I believe the R.java file isn't being generated at all. I can't find it in my project file tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all of your value folders, correct errors, clean project, and rebuild project. That is what tripped me up a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Fully collapse the file tree until only the project is visible. Wait. Clean. Wait. Should work now.
Are you using the latest software? I didn't have this bug for months. You might want to update eclipse, ADT and the eclipse plugin.

Comment: Sounds like serious f**k up. Create new project, copy resource files, copy java files, copy manifest.